# How to see the reports after all filters are applied?

Tags: powerbi

I want to select all the filters that I want to apply first and then after clicking a button I want to see the changes on the reports.

But, in power Bi Desktop, as soon as I select a slicer or any filter, it will be reflected on the reports. I don't want that. I want to see the changes after selecting all the filters.

Refer to the image for more information.

[image: view of the table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn on [Query reduction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-directquery-about#report-design-guidance) for your report by selecting `Filter selections` (and if you want `Slicer selections` too) from `File` -> `Options and settings` -> `Options` -> `CURRENT FILE` -> `Query reduction`:

[image]

After that `Apply filter` command will apper next to your filters:

[image]

And you will be able to select values for multiple filters and only after that to refresh the contents of the report.